# Disable caching of HTML template files on apache2 web server

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, caching

I'm trying to disable caching of HTML templates in my angular app.  It seems the easiest way to achieve this is disabling via Apache.  I placed this `.htaccess` file in my web root:

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
    FileETag None

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Note "CACHING IS DISABLED ON LOCALHOST"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
```

and restarted the server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but re-loading my browser with a soft refresh still shows the old, cached files.

Comment: did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: It should be cleared server side so that users don't have to manually clear to get updates